# Creating Spacers in VFL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, visual-format-language

[AutoLayoutbyExample via Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html)

Anyone have an example of how to create spacer views to set the spacing between labels equal in VFL?

```
labelsDictionary = [ "label1": label1,
                     "label2": label2,
                     "label3": label3,
                     "label4": label4 ]

let metrics = ["edgeSpacing": 20, "spacingBetween": 5, "labelWidth": 50]
let constraints = "H:|-(==edgeSpacing)-[label1(==labelWidth@999)]-[label2(==label1)]-[label3(==label1)]-[label3(==label1)]-[label4(==label1)]-(==edgeSpacing)-|"
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( format : constraints, 
                                                                   options : .allZeros, 
                                                                   metrics : metrics, 
                                                                     views : labelsDictionary))
```

I was just wondering how to create spacers in Swift to ensure that the width between the labels are always equal but of the lowest priority.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 3 spacer views, which mix with the 4 labels.

label1-spacer1-label2-spacer2-label3-spacer3-label4

Assuming you have all 7 views inside a containerView. Because label width may change according to its text, it is good to have equal space between them.

```
self.containerView.removeConstraints(containerView.constraints())

let views = ["label1": label1,
    "label2": label2,
    "label3": label3,
    "label4": label4,
    "spacer1": spacer1,
    "spacer2": spacer2,
    "spacer3": spacer3
 ]
let metrics = ["edgeSpacing": 20, "spacingBetween": 5]

//make spacers have equal width, and greater than 5, make all views center align vertically
var constH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-edgeSpacing-[label1]-[spacer1(>=spacingBetween)]-[label2]-[spacer2(==spacer1)]-[label3]-[spacer3(==spacer1)]-[label4]-edgeSpacing-|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: metrics, views: views)
view.addConstraints(constH)

//configure label1 vertical alignment
let constV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-edgeSpacing-[label1]-edgeSpacing-|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: metrics, views: views)
view.addConstraints(constV)

//make spacers have equal height
let constVForSpacer1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-edgeSpacing-[spacer1(==spacer2)]-edgeSpacing-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: metrics, views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVForSpacer1)

let constVForSpacer2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-edgeSpacing-[spacer2(==spacer3)]-edgeSpacing-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: metrics, views: views)
view.addConstraints(constVForSpacer2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to find another way to achieve what I wanted:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
  super.updateConstraints()
  for labelName in labelsDictionary.keys {
  self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[\(labelName)]-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: labelsDictionary))
}


self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label2, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label3, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 0.6, constant: 0))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label4, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0))
}
```